# Where can I safely switch characters?

Tags: state-of-decay

In *State of Decay*, I can switch characters outside of the safe houses when I am not in a car.

The last time I did that, I got a loading screen and after it finished, my character was dead.
This isn't the kind of game where I really want to risk my people's lives.

So where is it safe to switch?
(Outposts, ally places, clean houses)

Comment: What was the situation when you switched? I switch characters sometimes when I need to get home quickly, and have never had anyone die as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a loading screen is normal if you switch character when standing far away from home; but to have someone die after you switch away from them, I've never experienced it.

Where were you standing when you switched? Were you fighting with that character when you switched away?

Anyway, to safely switch character, make sure you are not fighting or standing at a high spot (like a survey point).

Answer (score 0):

the most secured and easy moment to switch a character is when you standing in your home

Comment: This adds nothing that isn't already said in the current answer.

Comment: He also is correct. This is the only real way to guarantee your character's safety. Otherwise they are at risk and can die for "being out and about".